# "Type variable has no meaning in this context"

Tags: python, type-variables

I have some machine learning model classes subclassed from XGBoost, Sklearn and TF and I have a factory method that takes a model name and returns a specific implementation and to have a correct return type from the factory I defined a TypeVar. Here MinXGBModel, MinRandomForestModel, MinDenseModel and MinMLPModel are my task-specific subclasses :

```py
from typing import TypeVar

PredictiveModel = TypeVar('PredictiveModel', 
                          MinXGBModel, 
                          MinRandomForestModel, 
                          MinDenseModel, 
                          MinMLPModel)


def predictive_model_factory(model_type: str) -> PredictiveModel:
    if model_type == "XGB":
        return MinXGBModel
    elif model_type == "TF":
        return MinDenseModel
    elif model_type == "RF":
        return MinRandomForestModel
    elif model_type == "MLP":
        return MinMLPModel
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f'Unknown model type {model_type}. '
                                  'Allowed model types are ("XGB", "RF", "TF", "MLP")')
```

This works fine but when I actually go to get the model class from a factory:

```py
model_cls: PredictiveModel = predictive_model_factory(model_type=model_type)
```

the linter highlights reference to `PredictiveModel` and says that *"Type variable PredictiveModel has no meaning in this context"*.

I don't use TypeVars very often so probably I'm doing something incorrectly but not sure what exactly. I had a look but couldn't find explanation for this message.

Comment: Well, it's technically correct -- type variables have no meaning in the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TypeVar` is used for genetic types, eg. if a function can take an argument of any type and return the same type, you would annotate it as:

```
T = TypeVar("T")

def same(x: T) -> T:
    return x
```

It means that the return type is the same as the type of argument `x`. Note that although the function can return any type, this is not the same as annotating it with `Any`.

On the other hand, doing this would have no meaning (there is no way to tell what the type `T` is).

```
T = TypeVar("T")

def same() -> T:
    return 7
```

The question contains similar code, where the type of the returned value cannot be determined.

If the idea is that it can return any of a several types, it should be annotated as a union of types:

```
def predictive_model_factory(model_type: str
        ) -> Union[MinXGBModel, MinRandomForestModel,
                   MinDenseModel, MinMLPModel]
    ...
```

### Additionally

BTW, there's is an additional problem in the question. That function's return type is actually `type`, because it returns a class and not an instance of a class. So it actually would be correctly annotated as `Union[Type[MinXGBModel], Type[MinRandomForestModel], Type[MinDenseModel], Type[MinMLPModel]]`. Now, that is a long type annotation!

This raises other questions:
Why don't those classes all inherit from a base class (let's call it `Model`), so that the function can simply return `Type[Model]`?

Also, the function could be the factory, instead of just returning a factory. It could instantiate the model and then it's return type would be just `Model`.

Comment: Actually all classes here inherit from one base model, I just forgot about it. Thanks for the explanation. I completely misunderstood the use case for genetic types.